# How to get a message sent to a particular email address according to subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a relative starter to Rails and am curious if there is a way in which a message on a 'Contact' page of a website can be sent to a particular email address depending on the subject chosen. I'm using Simple Form to generate a form and this is what I have on the 'Contact' page:

```
<%= f.input :subject, collection: [:Curriculum, :Jobs, :Other], prompt: 'Subject', required: true, error: 'You must select one' %>
```

In my contact.rb file, I have defined my headers method as:

```
def headers
    {
        subject: "Contact Form",
        to: "******.*******@gmail.com",
        from: %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
end
```

This is what I'd like to accomplish:

1) User selects 'Curriculum'. Message gets sent to, e.g. 'headteacher@school.org'.
2) User selects 'Other'. Message gets sent to, e.g. 'info@school.org'.
3) User selects 'Jobs'. Message gets sent to, e.g. 'hr@school.org'.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by setting up two models with a one-to-many association:

```
class Inquiry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subject
end

class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :inquiries 
end
```

While you could use a hardcoded hash, a yaml file or some other solution using rows in the database decouples your application logic from the specific implementation details. Storing Inquiry records in the db also gives you resilience against email failures.

And lets setup a route controller and view for Inquiries:

```
resources :inquiries, only: [:new, :create]
```

---

```
class InquiriesController
  def new
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new
  end

  def create
    @inquiry = Inquiry.new(inquiry_params)

    if @inquiry.save
      # This is just an example showing how you would get the data:
      send_mail(
        to: @inquiry.subject.email
        subject: @inquiry.subject.title
        body: @inquiry.message
      )
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def inquiry_params
    params.require(:inquiry).permit(:email, :name ,:message, :subject_id)
  end
end
```

---

```
<%= form_for(@inquiry) do |f| %>
   # ...
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :subject_id, 'Subject' %>
     <%= f.collection_select(:subject_id, Subject.all, :id, :name, prompt: true) %>
   </div>
   <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```